# Timeout Error in Selenium even after using implicit wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me with this timeout error .. Instead of using implicit wait, I am not sure why it still giving me timeout error. I am new to Selenium.. Here is my Base class:

```
public class BaseClass {
 public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void SetUpDriver (){
        //WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ketaki.naik\\Selenium\\Gecko_new\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32-1\\geckodriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
        String driver_name= "webdriver.gecko.driver";
        String driver_location = "C:\\Users\\ketaki.naik\\Selenium\\Gecko_new\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32-1\\geckodriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ketaki.naik\\Selenium\\Gecko_new\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win32-1\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty(driver_name,driver_location); 
        /*driver = new FirefoxDriver();*/
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://uat-pepsico.base.website");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        @Test
        public void AClickloginToApplication (){
        //driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("******");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("*********");
        driver.findElement(By.id("_submit")).click();

        }
```

AND I am extending this base class to my  MediaTouchPoints class, which should ideally open a excel sheet of the report:

```
public class MediaTouchPoints extends BaseClass {

    @Test
    public void MediaType1() {

    try{
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='reports']/a")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        System.out.println("Your exception is from MediaType1===" + E);
    }
    }

@Test
public void MediaType2() {
 int this_one = -1;
// System.out.println("I am inside MediaTYpe2");        

 try{
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


         List<WebElement> ReportMenu =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu-title menu_level_1 collapse in']//li/a/span"));

            //System.out.println("List from the menu===" + ReportMenu);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

           for (int i=0;i<ReportMenu.size();i++)
           {

            WebElement element = ReportMenu.get(i);

            String innerhtml= element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            //System.out.println("Element is===" + element);

            //System.out.println(innerhtml);


           //Thread.sleep(1000);
            if(innerhtml.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(("Media Touch-points")))
            {
                    this_one = i;
                    break;


           }
            System.out.println("I am here..LA LA LA");
            /*else {
                System.out.println("I have not performed IF-----");
            }*/
           }
        }
        catch(Exception E){
            System.out.println("Your exception is from MediaType2 ******====" + E);

        }

        if (this_one > -1)
        {
            try{
                  List<WebElement> ReportMenu =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu-title menu_level_1 collapse in']//li/a"));

                   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                   WebElement element = ReportMenu.get(this_one);
                   element.click();
                  // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='budgets_table_wrapper']/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a")).click();
                   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='budgets_table']/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]/a")).click();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                catch(Exception E)
                  {
                    System.out.println("Your exception is from 2nd test====" + E);

                  }

        }

 }

        @Test
        public void MediaType3(){

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='excel_export']")).click();
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ptp_table_wrapper']/div[1]/a[2]/span")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } 


    /*   @Test
       public void SelectProject() throws InterruptedException{

           Thread.sleep(10000);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='budgets_table_wrapper']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/a")).click();
           System.out.println("i want top click on Select button"); */

        @Test(priority=4)
        public void CampaignStatusReport_4() throws AWTException
        {
         try{
       // System.out.println("I am here....");
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        /*driver.switchTo().frame("ModelFrametitle");*/
        Robot object=new Robot();

        // Press Enter
        object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        // Release Enter
        object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println("My Exception is=== " + E);

        }

        }    

      /* @AfterClass
        public void CloseWindow (){
            driver.quit();


        }*/

    }
```

Below are errors:

```
1523434293660   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:19624
1523434296927   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1523434300402   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1523434306760   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62931
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1523434307188   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Apr 11, 2018 9:11:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Apr 11, 2018 9:12:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Your exception is from MediaType1===org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: timeouts
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ABCLAPTOP23', ip: '172.16.0.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.SsTh4gNfMgDB, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=59.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=15892.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt, moz:webdriverClick=true}]
Session ID: ef372642-2445-43ee-9eac-e210229f397f
Apr 11, 2018 9:12:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Your exception is from MediaType2 ******====org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: timeouts
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ABCLAPTOP23', ip: '172.16.0.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.SsTh4gNfMgDB, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=59.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=15892.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt, moz:webdriverClick=true}]
Session ID: ef372642-2445-43ee-9eac-e210229f397f
Apr 11, 2018 9:12:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
My Exception is=== org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: timeouts
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ABCLAPTOP23', ip: '172.16.0.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\ketaki.naik\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.SsTh4gNfMgDB, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=59.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=15892.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt, moz:webdriverClick=true}]
Session ID: ef372642-2445-43ee-9eac-e210229f397f
PASSED: AClickloginToApplication
PASSED: MediaType1
PASSED: MediaType2
PASSED: CampaignStatusReport_4
FAILED: MediaType3
```

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? At which line? Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Please don't show your credential in public site

Comment: This code was working nicely before- Say two months ago,.when i ran again today, i am getting this error :*(

Comment: @J0ki When you add the highlight markup to the error logs they gets truncated and debugging becomes tough. Please consider to preserve the error stack trace format as it is.

Comment: @DebanjanB you want the complete error stack ?

Comment: @KetakiNaik Yeah, the error stack trace helps in debugging

Comment: I think its erroring out somewhere in MediaType2, its not reaching out in my for loop and not able to locate Media Touch-points, My script is running way faster than page loading

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ABCLAPTOP23', ip: '172.16.0.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

It is clear from your error logs that :

- The *Selenium Client* is not getting recognized as in :

  ```
  Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
  ```
- The *FirefoxDriver Server* is not getting recognized back as in :

  ```
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  ```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_121** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u121*  and the current  *Selenium Client v3.11.0*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v59.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Okay, let me update as per your suggestions and i will get back.. Thanks a lot for a quick help